# If name is in a column, turn the column into a date format Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Context**

I want to dynamically change the data format in the respective columns of the below to a proper date format: I used this code but now want to make it dynamic. The original number formats in the date columns are date/time formats from google finance. But I just want the format in dd/mm/yyyy.

[image]

This was my original code:

```
function Dateformats() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Within the values copied spreadsheet, columns that have 'Date' will be the subject of this function
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Values (Live Data copied)')
 // var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Values (Live Data copied)")
  var dataList = sheet.getRangeList(['A:A', 'C:C', 'E:E', 'G:G', 'I:I', 'K:K', 'M:M', 'O:O']);
    dataList.setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

}
```

New code for dynamic results

```
  function Dateformats() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Within the values copied spreadsheet, columns that have 'Date' will be the subject of this function
  var range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName('Values (Live Data copied)!Date')
 
  if(range !== null){
    range.setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
  }
}
```

Both work though the latter does not actually show up on the sheet. The date formats still remain unchanged.

**Problem**

Is anyone aware of a fix for the dynamic reformating of columns that have 'Dates' in them?

Comment: also in the second code snippet you provided you need to pass a named range, not a sheet name. Given that `range` is null you don't get any errors but that does not mean that your script works. It just does not do anything and no errors are generated. Google what a named range is or read the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to understand what a name range is.

Comment: also the second snippet won't give you a "dynamic" solution because you still need to create named ranges for the columns separately which is a manual work again.

Comment: So I'd still need to input the columns I want this to include? What if I used the getRange() function where it looked through the entire spreadsheet to find columns with this text? Also, updated question based on your first response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to identify whether a column contains a date object. If it contains a date object, you want to change the format of the date from timestamp to a date.

The following script:

- will determine the type of each column based on the `4th` row and it will return `true` if the type is date or `false` otherwise. I use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to check for date elements based on this condition:

  `typeof em.getMonth === 'function'`
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) column of type `date` set the format of the whole column.

### Solution:

```
function Dateformats() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Values (Live Data copied)')
  const checkTypes = sheet.getRange(4,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).
                   getValues().
                   flat().
                   map(em=>typeof em.getMonth === 'function');
  checkTypes.forEach((ct,i)=>{
        if(ct){
           sheet.getRange(4,i+1,sheet.getMaxRows(),1).
           setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
        }
  });
}
```

Please note again that I am using the `4th` row to determine the type of each column. Therefore, this row should contain the same type as the rest of the cells in the same column. Namely, the solution won't work if a column contains multiple types of data.